# Manatee.Trello Limited to 50 labels in a board

Tags: manatee.trello

I am getting back all of the labels for a board and I guess we are hitting up against some limit now.

```
var board = new Board(boardString);
foreach (var label in board.Labels.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Name))
{
    Console.WriteLine(label.Name + " " + label.Id);
}
```

We have over 50 labels now and no dice? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you update the question with what you are seeing? An error, only 49 labels, etc?

Comment: It looks like to has a [default of 50 for the limit](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/board#get-1-boards-board-id-labels).  Please add an issue in my [github repo](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Trello) so I can track adding an extension method for the label collections to modify the limit.

Comment: For reference: [github issue](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Trello/issues/71)

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.17.0, I have added `BoardLabelCollection.Filter(LabelColor)` and `BoardLabelCollection.Limit(int)` to support this feature.